# How to get the bootstrap css to work in index.html in the below structure?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

Right now when I run *gulp build* everything compiles and when I go to localhost in development mode, I can see the main Angular application.  But the bootstrap css files don't seem to be there.

There is no error in the Google Chrome console.  What do I need to fix.

```
'use strict';

// vendor
require('bower/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router');
require('bower/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage');
require('bower/bootstrap');
require('bower/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap');
require('bower/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls');

//app modules
//require('./common/cat/cat.module');
//require('./modules/showroom/showroom.module');
require('./modules/fair_offer/fair_offer.module');

// app assets
//require('./app.less');

// main module config
//module.exports = angular.module('greatestApp', [
module.exports = angular.module('fairOfferApp', [
        'ui.router',
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        //common,
        'greatestApp.catService',

        // modules
        'greatestApp.showroom'
        'fairOfferApp.fair_offer'
    ])


    .config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/fair_offer');
    })

    .run(function($log){
       /*jshint ignore:line */
    })
;
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
var path              = require('path');
var webpack           = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var appRoot           = path.join(__dirname, '/src');
var bowerRoot         = path.join(__dirname, '/bower_components');
var bootstrapPath     = path.join(__dirname, '/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap');
var jqueryPath        = path.join(__dirname, '/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min');

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    singleRun: true,

    // The entry point
    entry: [
        path.join(appRoot, '/app/app.js')
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './static'),
        publicPath: './',
        filename: '[hash].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
    },


    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less'
            },
            {
                // require raw html for partials
                test: /\.html$/, loader: 'ng-cache'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            },
            {
              test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file"
            },
            {
              test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader:"url?prefix=font/&limit=5000"
            },
            {
              test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
            },
            {
              test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
            }
        ],

        // don't parse some dependencies to speed up build.
        noParse: [
            path.join(bowerRoot, '/angular-ui-router'),
            path.join(bowerRoot, '/angular-mocks'),
            path.join(bowerRoot, '/angular'),
            path.join(bowerRoot, '/less')
        ],
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            bower: bowerRoot,
            'bootstrap.less': bootstrapPath,
            'jquery': jqueryPath

        },

        extensions: [
            '',
            '.js',
            '.less',
            '.css'
        ],

        root: [appRoot],
        moduleDirectories: [bootstrapPath]
    },


    plugins: [
        // bower.json resolving
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin([
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin('bower.json', ['main'])
        ], ['normal', 'loader']),

        // disable dynamic requires
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/.*$/, /a^/),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'angular': 'exports?window.angular!bower/angular',
            '$': "jquery",
            'jQuery': "jquery"
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/src/index.html'
        }),

    ],

};
```

*Directory tree*

```
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── app.less
│   │   ├── app.spec.js
│   │   ├── common
│   │   │   └── cat
│   │   │       ├── cat.controller.js
│   │   │       ├── cat.controller.spec.js
│   │   │       ├── cat.directive.js
│   │   │       ├── cat.directive.spec.js
│   │   │       ├── cat.less
│   │   │       ├── cat.module.js
│   │   │       ├── cat.service.js
│   │   │       └── cat.service.spec.js
│   │   ├── modules
│   │   │   ├── fair_offer
│   │   │   │   ├── fair_offer.controller.js
│   │   │   │   ├── fair_offer.html
│   │   │   │   ├── fair_offer.less
│   │   │   │   └── fair_offer.module.js
│   │   │   └── showroom
│   │   │       ├── showroom.controller.js
│   │   │       ├── showroom.controller.spec.js
│   │   │       ├── showroom.html
│   │   │       ├── showroom.less
│   │   │       └── showroom.module.js
│   │   ├── normalize.less
│   │   └── vendor.less
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── loader.gif
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
├── static
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── loader.gif
│   └── favicon.ico
├── tags
└── webpack.config.js
```

Comment: I don't see bower_components on your Directory Tree.

Comment: bower_components are there, I just didn't include them for brevity....tree outputs something 17K lines for this project

Comment: Try to add `require('bootstrap.less');` in js-file.

Comment: If I do that in src/app/app.js I get a build error - which js file did you mean?